# Spring batch set log4j file appender name from #{jobParameters['']}

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-batch

I have this log4j property configuration:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${logfilepath}
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I also have this `#{jobParameters['logfilepath']}` that contains the file path where I want log4j write the log of my batch.

How can I pass this value to `log4j.properties` file?

I want to specify by command line argument, the path of the log file where log4j has to write.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can do that by defining a job listener. Sample below. Make sure to remove existing appenders if you only want to use the new appender.

```
public class CommonLoggerListener implements JobExecutionListener{

    @Value("#{jobParameters['LOG_FILE_NAME']}")
    String fileName;

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
       Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.demo");
       Class loggerIntrospected = logger.getClass();
       Field fields[] = loggerIntrospected.getDeclaredFields();
       for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                String fieldName = fields[i].getName();
                if (fieldName.equals("logger")) {
                    fields[i].setAccessible(true);
                    org.apache.log4j.Logger loggerImpl = (org.apache.log4j.Logger) fields[i].get(logger);
                    loggerImpl.addAppender(new RollingFileAppender(<layout>, fileName));
                }
            }
    }
}
```